# Unable to edit a form in site and also in admin site in django

Tags: django, forms

I am working on a project which has 2 apps: account and blog. Account has all the login,logout ,password change , registration views and urls etc.

In the blog app I have 4 views to list all the posts , detail of a post , create a new post(@login_required) and edit a post(@login_required).

While the create a post view(post_create) is  working fine and allows a logged in user to add a new post with tags(using django-taggit app), edit view doesn't save the form data at all. I try to edit a post using the admin site, but to my surprise the data is not changed there also. i have tried a lot of solutions and even read a lot of related forums on similar problem but can't figure out what exactly is wrong.

Problem in one line: Can't edit and save the post form , can't edit a post on admin site.

I am putting my code for the models , forms and views here.

```
 #models.py
 class PublishedManager(models.Manager):

    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(PublishedManager,self).get_queryset().filter(status='published') 



class Post(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('draft','Draft'),
        ('published','Published'),
    )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250,unique_for_date='publish')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='blog_posts')
    body = models.TextField()
    publish = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10,
                          choices=STATUS_CHOICES,
                          default='draft')
    objects = models.Manager()# default manager
    published = PublishedManager()# custom

    tags = TaggableManager()

    class Meta:
        ordering =('-publish',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
    # to build canonical URL for Post objects using post_detail URL.
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('blog:post_detail',
                   args=[self.publish.year,
                         self.publish.strftime('%m'),
                         self.publish.strftime('%d'),
                         self.slug])
    # overide save() method to generate slug field automatically based on  title
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = slugify(self.title)
            super(Post,self).save(*args,**kwargs)
#views.py
@login_required
def post_create(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PostCreateForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():

            new_post = form.save(commit=False)

            new_post.author = request.user
            new_post.publish = timezone.now()

            new_post.save()
            form.save_m2m()

            #messages.success(request,'Post added successfully')

            return redirect(new_post.get_absolute_url())
    else:
        form = PostCreateForm()

    context = {
        "form": form,
    }
    return render(request,'blog/post/create.html',context)

@login_required
def post_edit(request,pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post,id = pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PostCreateForm(data=request.POST,instance=post)

        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.author = request.user
            post.publish = timezone.now()

            post.save()
            form.save_m2m()



            return redirect(post.get_absolute_url())
    else:
        form = PostCreateForm(instance=post)

    return render(request,'blog/post/create.html',{'form':form})




def post_list(request,tag_slug=None):

    object_list = Post.published.all()
    tag = None

    if tag_slug:
        tag = get_object_or_404(Tag,slug=tag_slug)
        object_list = object_list.filter(tags__in=[tag])

    # searching posts , tag search not there

    query = request.GET.get("q")
    if query:

        object_list = object_list.filter(
            Q(title__icontains=query)|
            Q(body__icontains=query)|
            Q(author__first_name__icontains=query)|
            Q(author__last_name__icontains=query)).distinct()

    paginator = Paginator(object_list,3) # 3 posts in each page
    page = request.GET.get('page') # indicates current page number

    try:
        posts = paginator.page(page)

    except PageNotAnInteger: # if page is not an integer deliver the first page
        posts = paginator.page(1)

    except EmptyPage:
        # If page is out of range deliver last page of results
        posts = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    return render(request,'blog/post/list.html',
              {'page':page,
               'posts':posts,
               'tag':tag})


def post_detail(request,year,month,day,post):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post,
                         slug=post,
                         status='published',
                         publish__year=year,
                         publish__month=month,
                         publish__day=day)

    # list of similar posts
    post_tags_ids = post.tags.values_list('id',flat=True)

    similar_posts = Post.published.filter(tags__in=post_tags_ids).exclude(id=post.id)

    similar_posts = similar_posts.annotate(same_tags=Count('tags'))\
                            .order_by('-same_tags','-publish')[:4]
    return render(request,
              'blog/post/detail.html',
              {'post':post,
               'similar_posts':similar_posts})

#forms.py
class PostCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = (
            "title",
            "body",
            "status",
            "tags",
    )
#admin.py
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Post

class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title','slug','author','publish','status')
    list_filter = ('status','created','publish','author')
    search_fields = ('title','body')
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug':('title',)}
    raw_id_fields = ('author',)
    date_hierarchy = 'publish'
    ordering = ['status','publish']

admin.site.register(Post,PostAdmin)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your'e only calling the save (super) method if the slug is empty. So your code schould look like: (note the intending of the last line)

```
class Post(models.Model):
    # ...
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        super(Post,self).save(*args,**kwargs)
```

Comment: Yes it worked. thanks. one more thing why can't I add a new post from the admin site.It shows that I should have a primary key for the post model first for a ManyToMany relationship.i guess it is because of tags field but is there a way in which I can add a ppst from admin site.

Comment: Try to disable tags and check if this is the problem. I don't see in your code where there could be a problem. django-taggit usually also works before saving an instance.